# pgfplots: put a tick each first day of a month

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I have a dateplot and I need to put a tick each first (or n-th) day of a month programmatically. I set up the following mwe which doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\newcommand{\dateticks}{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,11}
    {\ifnum\i<10
       2016-0\i-01,%
     \else
       2016-\i-01,%
     \fi
       2016-12-01
     }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
%xtick={\dateticks},        % <- This doesn't work
xtick={2016-01-01,2016-02-01,2016-03-01,2016-04-01,2016-05-01,2016-06-01,%
       2016-07-01,2016-08-01,2016-09-01,2016-10-01,2016-11-01,2016-12-01},
xticklabel=\day/\month,
xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1) Any advice?

2) Is there a better (and more user-independent) way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Could you give us a drawing of what you want it to do? I'm having trouble visualizing what you want to happen.

Comment: @Artillect I've edited the mwe to plot what I would expect to get. If you uncomment the first xtick line and comment the second, you get the error. The code should set up the uncommented xtick line for me in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that no expansion takes place when the option `xtick={\dateticks}` is processed. `xtick` represents a list with just one element, namely `\dateticks`.

One way around this is to put the picture into a macro and provide the list as an argument.

```
\newcommand\mygraph[1]{... xtick={#1} ...}
```

Now it is easy to expand `\dateticks` before handing it over to `\mygraph`.

```
\expandafter\mygraph\expandafter{\dateticks}
```

Before doing so we have to make sure that `\dateticks` contains the list of dates, and nothing else.

```
\newcommand\dateticks{2016-01-01}
\foreach \i in {2,...,12}{\xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\ifnum\i<10 0\fi\i-01}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\newcommand\dateticks{2016-01-01}
\foreach \i in {2,...,12}{\xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\ifnum\i<10 0\fi\i-01}}
\newcommand\mygraph[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
      [date coordinates in=x,
       xtick={#1},
       xticklabel=\day/\month,
       xticklabel style={rotate=90},
      ]
      \addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}
\expandafter\mygraph\expandafter{\dateticks}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is a way to generate the ticks for an arbitrary start date and an arbitrary number of months. After executing

```
\setdateticks{YYYY-MM-DD}{N}
```

the macro `\dateticks` contains a list of N dates starting with YYYY-MM-DD and incrementing the month by one from date to date. E.g., `\setdateticks{2016-12-01}{3}` sets `\dateticks` to `2016-12-01,2017-01-01,2017-02-01`. Here is the code defining `\setdateticks`.

```
\newcommand\dateticks{}
\newcommand\splitdate{}
\def\splitdate#1-#2#3-#4-%
  {\def\YYYY{#1}%
   \ifnum#2=0\def\MM{#3}\else\def\MM{#2#3}\fi
   \def\DD{#4}%
  }
\newcommand\setdateticks[2]%
  {\def\dateticks{#1}%
   \bgroup
   \splitdate#1-%
   \foreach \i in {2,...,#2}
     {\pgfmathtruncatemacro\mm{mod(\MM+\i-2,12)+1}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yyyy{\YYYY+divide(\MM+\i-2,12)}%
      \xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,\yyyy-\ifnum\mm<10 0\fi\mm-\DD}%
     }%
   \egroup
  }
```

And here is the complete code for the diagram above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\newcommand\dateticks{}
\def\splitdate#1-#2#3-#4-%
  {\def\YYYY{#1}%
   \ifnum#2=0\def\MM{#3}\else\def\MM{#2#3}\fi
   \def\DD{#4}%
  }
\newcommand\setdateticks[2]%
  {\def\dateticks{#1}%
   \bgroup
   \splitdate#1-%
   \foreach \i in {2,...,#2}
     {\pgfmathtruncatemacro\mm{mod(\MM+\i-2,12)+1}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yyyy{\YYYY+divide(\MM+\i-2,12)}%
      \xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,\yyyy-\ifnum\mm<10 0\fi\mm-\DD}%
     }%
   \egroup
  }
\newcommand\mygraph[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}%
      [date coordinates in=x,
       xtick={#1},
       xticklabel=\day/\month,
       xticklabel style={rotate=90},
      ]
      \addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}
\setdateticks{2016-01-01}{12}
\expandafter\mygraph\expandafter{\dateticks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the second part of the question: is there a better (and more user-independent) way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Luigi In which sense better? What do you mean by user-independent? If you specify which parts should be flexible/parametrized, I can adapt the solution (or someone else, if I don't know how to do it).

Comment: Given the start date, the step and the last date (which can be even today, ie \year-\month-\day), the code should arrange the set for me. Something like 'xtick distance=\month'.

Comment: @Luigi I've added some code to compute the list for arbitrary start dates and for an arbitrary number of months.

Comment: I've found out the `xtick/.expanded`key which, used together with the `xdef`macro, can solve the issue in the original question without having to put all the plot inside a command (see my own answer). Anyway your answer has been helpful to explain to me the reason of the error. Moreover, I appreciate your effort in improving the original code in a more programmatic fashion. Therefore I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Luigi Thanks for this bug report. The problem is that numerals starting with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers, which is ok for 00 to 07, but 08 and 09 are not valid numerals. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for me is to use the `xtick/.expanded` key instead of the usual `xtick` plus the `xdef` macro as in the following working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\def\dateticks{2016-01-01}
\foreach \i in {2,...,12}
  {\xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\ifnum\i<10 0\fi\i-01}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xtick/.expanded={\dateticks},
  xticklabel=\day/\month,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```