# pgfplots: put a tick each first day of a month with abbreviated month name

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I'm trying to get a plot with xticks with the first day of the month, as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357026/pgfplots-put-a-tick-each-first-day-of-a-month) and using abbreviated month names, as it is done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517587/display-only-first-tick-label-using-pgfplots). This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\def\monthnames{{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}}

\begin{document}
\def\dateticks{2016-Jan-01}
\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
    {\xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\pgfmathparse{\monthnames[Mod(\i,12)]}\pgfmathresult-01}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xtick/.expanded={\dateticks},
  xticklabel=\day/\month,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this produces the error:
`Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 11.` Not sure what the problem is here because I don't have (at least explicitly) a conditional statement.

Any ideas on how to generate the `\dateticks` macro with the abbreviated month names? What I would like it the following figure, but with the month names instead of numbers:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\def\monthnames{{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}}
\def\dateticks{2016-Jan-01}
\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
    {\pgfmathparse{\monthnames[Mod(\i,12)]}%
    \xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\pgfmathresult-01}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels/.expanded=\dateticks,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLDER ANSWER**: If you want to use the month names from your list, you can use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\def\monthnames{{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel=\pgfmathtruncatemacro\mmonth{\month}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymonth}{\monthnames[Mod(11+\mmonth,12)]}%
    \day/\mymonth,
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the same result can be obtained with `xticklabel=\day/\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  date coordinates in=x,
  xticklabel=\day/\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\month},
  xticklabel style={rotate=90},
]
\addplot coordinates {(2016-01-23,10) (2016-03-05,20) (2016-09-14,10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger's cat! Do you know why the error in my code? I had a hard time finding why it wasn't working, any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: @kmundnic Yes. There are two issues. First, `\pgfmathparse` is not expandable, so you would need `\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
    {\pgfmathparse{\monthnames[Mod(\i,12)]}\xdef\dateticks{\dateticks,2016-\pgfmathresult-01}}`. Then the error when generating the list disappears. Second, if I am not mistaken, this list is not suitable for `xtick/.expanded={\dateticks},`. You could use `xticklabel/.expanded={\dateticks},` but the result is probably not what you want.